# I can't write to standard input of a Fortran program in Sublime 3

Tags: fortran, sublimetext3

I can't write any input for the Fortran `read` statement from keyboard, and sublime REPL hasn't the Fortran program.

In other words, I don't know how I can input something to the standard input of the program.

The code statement:

```
  write(*,*) "NAME:"
  read(*,*) a%name
```

The string "NAME:" is printed in the output window, but there is no way to write the input there.

[image: Sublime 3 with the source code and output.]

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Code should normally be entered *as text* but I understand you need to show the user interface of the editor. If you run the editor from the command line, it should be possible to enter the input just there. If not, why not just run the program in  another command line?

Comment: I really  appreciate that.